# Extract Text From Images,ocr

Tags: windows, ocr

Extract Text From Images?i have many images,i searched and found some online convertors but doesn't work becouse i have 10.000 image,so i need a mass tool,can someone help me with this,thank you

Comment: Nope. Not here. Sorry, voting to close and I suspect you'll get down votes

Comment: `Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers`

Comment: Question belongs in the **Software Reccomendation** group not here.